# How do I save state in Aptana/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana

I am using Aptana (based on Eclipse) as an IDE for ColdFusion development. My computer occasionally crashes or shuts down unexpectedly, and when restarting Aptana, my state (which files are open, etc) reverts to the last time that I properly closed Aptana. This is slightly annoying, as I have to close all the open files (that I usually haven't used in a while, as I generally leave Aptana perpetually open), and find and open all the files that I was working on when the computer shut down. Is there any way to "save" my current setup (other than shutting down and reopening Aptana)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's no way to do this from within Eclipse/Aptana, but there is a [plugin](http://eclipsenuggets.blogspot.co.il/2007/09/how-to-save-eclipse-ui-workbench-state_6644.html) that's been developed to allow you to save the UI state. (I assume this would work for Aptana as well.)